# Why is my nunjucks page not being interpreted properly?

Tags: node.js, express, nunjucks

In a node,js app using express.js, I have a piece of middleware that redirects to a session ended page written in nunjucks where need be.

The redirection works put the page is output as written and not as html. For some reason it's not being recognised as nunjucks.

```
nunjucks.configure(['views',
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/govuk-frontend/'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/govuk-frontend/govuk/components/'),
    path.join(__dirname, 'app/views/')
], {
    autoescape: true,
    express: app
});

const endSession = (req, res, next) => {
  if (config.switchPage) {
   res.render(__dirname + '/app/views/pages/session-ended.html');
   return;
  } else {
    next();
  } 
};

app.use(endSession);
```

Elsewhere, I call the page with:

```
res.redirect('/decision/session-ended');
```

and it works fine.
I've tried swapping the sendfile for the redirect but get the following error message on the page:
This page isn’t working
localhost redirected you too many times.
Try clearing your cookies.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

==== ADDITIONAL INFO ====

This middleware gets kicked off here:

```
const getApplicationRef = (req, res) => {
    req.session.accessPage = '/decision/application-reference';
    res.render('pages/application-reference', { appRef: req.session.appRef });
};
```

which invokes:

```
const express = require('express');

const router = express.Router();

const { getApplicationRef, submitApplicationRef } = require('../../services/handler/application/application-ref-handler');

router.get('/', getApplicationRef);
router.post('/', submitApplicationRef);

module.exports = router;
```

getApplicationRef =

```
const getApplicationRef = (req, res) => {
    req.session.accessPage = '/decision/application-reference';
    res.render('pages/application-reference', { appRef: req.session.appRef });
};
```

And here's some code that renders the page properly:

```
const getSecurityCode = (req, res) => {
    if (req.session.appRef) {
        req.session.accessPage = '/decision/security-code';
        res.render('pages/security-code', { secCode: req.session.secCode });
    } else {
        res.redirect('/decision/session-ended');
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the code you've shown in your question contains no nunjucks code at all so it's hard to see where you expect things to be using nunjucks.  You aren't showing us very much specifics in your code so we can just offer the general advice.

If you want nunjucks to render the page, you need to call `res.render("yourtemplate")`, not `res.sendFile(somefile)` and you need to have properly registered nunjucks as your template engine.

If you're using `res.redirect('/decision/session-ended');`, then you need a route for `/decision/session-ended` that calls `res.render()` appropriately and does NOT do further redirecting and you need to make sure that route is not redirected by your middleware (probably just by placing that route handler before your middleware).

For more detail, please show the entire code flow that is relevant here from when the session ends to all requests involved in that.

Comment: I'm now using render.res as suggested and have moved the code to just after where nunjucks is initialised. I've updated my posting to show this. Now I'm getting 'Template render error' on the page.

As I say, the page renders just fine when I call 'res.redirect('/decision/session-ended')from elsewhere so I know the nunjucks is just fine and I'm reluctant to show the nunjucks for reasons of client confidentially (which makes me sound an arse I know).

Comment: @jenkinz - Please show the code you are using when `'/app/views/pages/session-ended.html'` does render properly.  Is that template file expecting some data to be sent to it?  Not much else we can do here when you don't show us the whole code flow or the template or the code that you say works.

Comment: Have added more info. It's 1 in the morning here so I'm off to beddy-byes. Will be back in the morning,